# Does clearing browser cache mean clearing chrome.storage extension data?

Tags: database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm considering hiring a developer from upwork.com to build my chrome extension. He was saying he would need to build it using local storage, but I questioned him and asked why he couldn't use the chrome.storage API. His response was that if the user clears the browser cache, it would clear everything saved in the extension. That didn't seem right to me but I wanted to ask you all.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, even after clearing ALL browser data and cache if you are using `chrome.storage` API any data stored in that manner will still be present.

Unless you explicitly clear the extensions storage by command it will not be cleared.

Answer (score -1):

Extensions in Google Chrome will not be removed or preferences changed/cleared.

You are right that this will also depend on where your extension saves its preferences, for example, extensions may allow you to sign in and save your data in the cloud - whereas other may not. There are multiple ways to store this data, ask why an extension developer cannot develop a robust extension?